# Deploy on localhost doesn't work with json request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, iis-8

I'm deploying an asp.net mvc 4 website to IIS 8 in localhost (Windows 8.1 x64).It works fine in visual studio 2012 on debug mode, but when I deploy to IIS 8 the ajax request doesn't work at all, I get a 404 error for the request.By the way, I can CRUD to database anything the while is not a json request. Any suggestion ???!!!

This is my javascript code:

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".visibility").click(function () {
                var visibility = $(".visibility").attr("checked");
                var visibilityBool;
                if (visibility == "checked")
                    visibilityBool = true;
                else
                    visibilityBool = false;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Questionnaire/ChangeVisibility",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        "id": $(".questionnaire > h3").attr("data-id"),
                        "visibility": visibilityBool
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: If it is a 404 error then the path must not be correct. What is the path to /Questionnaire/ChangeVisibility on your localhost?

Comment: Check which URL your ajax request is trying to reach, modify according to it `url` option of ajax request

Comment: jay blanchard, yes path it is not correct but like I said it works fine when I'm working with visual studio and press F5. About your question, ChangeVisibility is a method inside QuestionnaireController, under controller folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the url, try [`UrlHelper.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
url: '@Url.Action("ChangeVisibility", "Questionnaire")'
```

A couple other things..

Instead of `$(".visibility").attr("checked")`, use `this.checked`. The attribute's value doesn't change when the user checks the checkbox.

Also, this should probably be a `post` request, not a `get`. If it has to be a `get` for some reason, use the ajax option `cache: false`.

Comment: Jason P works great, thank you!! but now a new problem arrives The first time that I click on the checkbox for change the visibility works fine, it saves the change made in the database and get me a 200 response, but when I click again doesn't save it and get me a 304, with not change in the database. I think it's about some related with the cache, could be?? or I'm wrong??

Comment: Now I notice that in different browser like chrome doens't happen this. It works fine!!!